# How to write a linked list to a file

Tags: c, linked-list, text-files

I'm a new programmer and I am having some troubles writing a linked list to a text file.
Here's my code:

```
typedef struct N {
  int code;
  char name[MAX1];
  int items;
  float price;
  struct N *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
  int code;
  char name[MAX1];
  int items;
  float price;
} product;

product p;
product *ptr = &p;
node_t *iterator = head;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+");


while (iterator != NULL) {
   p.code = iterator->code;
   strcpy(p.name, iterator->name);
   p.items = iterator->items;
   p.price = iterator->price;
   fwrite(ptr, 1, sizeof(product),fp);
   iterator = iterator->next;
}
```

at this point, I read from stream and display what I should have written on "newfile.txt", but all it prints out is '0' where there should be an integer/float and nothing where there should be a string.
I've also tried writing to the file a simple integer with fputs() and other functions, but it printed out random numbers.
In case you are wondering, since I haven't copied the whole code here, the list is NOT empty and I can display correctly all of the items in it.
I'm sorry if I haven't been clear, but this is my first post here. Hope someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: It's your decision, how to write it? you should decide...

Comment: I meant to use fwrite to write the whole struct at once and to keep the same "order" of the previous file where the datas to create the linked list where held..but it doesnt work..

Comment: How do you check what is in the file? It’s no surprise that your strings are not in there, but the numbers should be.

Comment: What does *"it doesn't work"* exactly mean?

Comment: If you intend for the file to be readable text, then you'll want to write each field individually with some delimiter between them, like a space, newline, etc.  If you are going to write the whole struct as a binary block like you've shown then you should be opening the file in binary mode.

Comment: I wrote to it using  fputs( 12 , fp); then I read the stream using fscanf(fp, "%d", &c) (int c previouly declared) and then I used printf("%d", c); but it printed random numbers like 26543

Comment: @RetiredNinja I did also try writing each field on its own, using fscanf for integers and fwrite for strings. Still '0'.

Comment: If you're having trouble reading the file back you should include that code as well.  A simple example of filling out one node, writing it, then reading it back should be enough to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you everyone, it works perfectly! I guess I  opened the file in a wrong mode, truth is, I just understood the difference!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following changes:

1. Divide the `struct` for each node into two `struct`s - one for holding the data and one for capturing the next pointer.

   ```
   typedef struct 
   {
     int code;
     char name[MAX1];
     int items;
     float price;
   } NodeData;

   typedef struct N {
      NodeData data;
     struct N *next;
   } node_t;
   ```
2. Now the function to write the contents of a linked list can be:

   ```
   fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+");

   // Get the size of the linked list and write as the first piece of data.
   size_t listSize = getLinkedListSize(head)

   fwrite(&listSize, 1, sizeof(size_t), fp);

   // Now write each node of the linked list.
   while (iterator != NULL) {
      fwrite(&(iterator->data), 1, sizeof(iterator->data), fp);
      iterator = iterator->next;
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why getting the size of the linked list and writing it as the first piece of data is important. Would you mind explaining it to me please? Thank you very much!

Comment: That will be useful at the time of reading the data back from file. You would know how many items are in the linked list. You would read the data  corresponding to the nodes in a `for` loop and not read any more or less than you need to.

Comment: Surely you can tell you've got to the end of the file by the EOF.

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite` just writes the binary representation of the data, rather than an ASCII representation as you might expect to see in a text file. An integer, for instance, will be represented by four `NUL` characters, which you won't be able to see. So your code might well be working.

If you want to write something out as *text*, use `fprintf`, e.g.:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d,%d,%lf,\"%s\"\n",
        iterator->code, iterator->items, iterator->price, iterator->name);
```

would be a rough approximation of CSV (note it doesn't escape characters inside the name).

By the way, why not just make add a member variable of `node_t` which is a `product`? Then you can avoid all that copying about.

Comment: Instead of fwrite then what do you suggest me to use?                    Regarding your second suggestion, you mean like : typedef  struct N { product P; struct N *next;} node_t ?

Comment: To write out as text, use `fprintf` (see edit). And yes, exactly like that.