# Writing nested struct to disk in C

Tags: c, serialization

So I have a struct that looks something like this (more or less):

```
typedef struct AST_STRUCT
{
    enum {
        AST_OBJECT,
        AST_REFERENCE,
        AST_VARIABLE,
        AST_VARIABLE_DEFINITION,
        AST_VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT,
        AST_VARIABLE_MODIFIER,
        AST_FUNCTION_DEFINITION,
        AST_FUNCTION_CALL,
        AST_NULL,
        AST_STRING,
        AST_CHAR,
        AST_FLOAT,
        AST_LIST,
        AST_BOOLEAN,
        AST_INTEGER,
        AST_COMPOUND,
        AST_TYPE,
        AST_BINOP,
        AST_NOOP,
        AST_BREAK,
        AST_RETURN,
        AST_IF,
        AST_ELSE,
        AST_WHILE,
        AST_ATTRIBUTE_ACCESS,
        AST_LIST_ACCESS,
        AST_NEW
    } type;

    struct AST_STRUCT* variable_value;
}
```

Now I would like to write this struct, serialized to the disk into a `.dat` file.
The problem is that as you can see, it has a field called `variable_value` .

I am using this function to write it to disk:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-structure-file-c/

I am also using the other function in that article to read it from the disk.
It appears as if the `variable_value` field on the struct is not loaded properly.
How would I write the entire struct to disk and maintain the data of the `variable_value` field?

I was first thinking about dumping the `variable_value` field into a separate file and then sort of "link it back" into the struct once I load it, but maybe there is another way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide us the code you are using to read/write your structure on disk ?

Comment: `variable_value` is a pointer to your structure `AST_STRUCT`; most likely to form a linked-list. Why do want to store memory address into file? i.e What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a linked list to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033922/how-to-write-a-linked-list-to-a-file)

Comment: Note that the serialization code in the geeksforgeeks link is garbage, because it doesn't mention any of the problems that come with them, pointer members being one of the problems. Writing structures directly should be avoided whenever possible, and serialize each member manually instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serialize a linked structure (I assume a tree, from the name "AST").

If we imagine for a second that you successfully did that and wrote it to disk, when you load it back, you'll allocate memory for the links in the tree, but the addresses (values of pointers) of these memory chunks are not guaranteed to be the same as the old ones. You will not be able to reconstruct the tree.

So you can't use the value of the addresses as links on the disk. You'll need to use some other method. These days, the popular method is the [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) format, which would work for you assuming that you don't have cross-links or back-links in the tree.

So what you need is a JSON C library. I've never used one, but here are a couple I found in 2 seconds:

- [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)
- [cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON)

Answer (score 0):

JSON and xml are perfectly good formats to use if you want to save your data as text. They do have issues with restoring multiple references to the same object, but even they can be resolved.

If the data is a simple link-list, you can simply restore the objects in order and repair the link-list yourself as you restore the objects. If the data structure is more complex than that you need a more generic solution.

If you really want to save the data as binary, then you need to fix up pointers when you reload. The main way to do this is to keep a map of saved addresses vs newly allocated addresses. If you really don't like the idea of emitting the saved addresses, you can use a serial number to represent each unique address you find.

For each object you save you have to record it's scalar address, and the type of object,  before you save the object itself.

For each pointer you save, you need to save the scalar address, and "remember" to later save that referenced object.

On restoring, when you restore an object you need to load the object based on its type, and create a mapping entry that shows how the saved address has turned into a restored address.

If an object contains any pointers, the address stored in those pointers is found by applying that mapping. However, you will often find that the object has not yet been loaded for that pointer, so you will also need to record a mapping from the saved scalar address to the address of the pointer. You can then either fix up all these unfinished pointers after you finish loading, or you can do it for a particular referenced object after that object is loaded.

You need to put in a little extra care to handle objects that support multiple inheritance, by noting that the pointer does not point to the root of the object.

But otherwise, this is just about all you need, plus considerations of versioning, endianness, padding - if you care about the longevity of the data you are saving.