# read a binary in (c) file containing different structs, which have pointer as member

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binaryfiles

I'm sorry if this is not well explained. I looked everywhere I can but I can't find a solution. I'm trying to read a binary file in c but the problem is it contains many structs with dependencies. I know how to read one struct type into a variable but not in this case. Here is an example of what I meant by dependency between structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Car;
typedef struct
{
    char c[10];
    int d;
    Car* cars;
} Seller;
typedef struct
{
    int e;
    Seller* sellers;
} Maker;
```

When reading, I have to be able to link each car to its seller and each seller to its maker.

Comment: When storing data on disk, you cannot (usefully) store addresses because there's no guarantee that the data will be read back into the same memory locations when it is read, even if it is the same program that writes and then reads the data.  Therefore you have to 'serialize' the data for disk storage.  That's a search term, but it will lead to lots of information about Java, etc.  Search for something like '`c language serialize structures`'.  Basically, you'll need to do something like create arrays of defined size in the file, and record indexes into those arrays in the structures on disk.

Comment: what is the file structure, you may share format with example? try to make a layout with code that help to better understand how you want this.

Comment: Once go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033922/how-to-write-a-linked-list-to-a-file

Comment: One can (usefully) store addresses because there's a guarantee that the data will be read back into the same memory locations when it is read if a specific address space mapping is created with `mmap()`.

Comment: If you plan to use `mmap()`, @Armali, then you have to use memory allocation that only places the data in the mapped memory — which means not using `malloc()` et al.

Answer (score 0):

You will have read each `nested structures` individually.

Example:

```
   Marker marker;
   fread(&marker.e, sizeof (int), 1, filePtr);

   marker.sellers = malloc(sizeof (*marker.sellers));
   fread(&marker.sellers->c , sizeof (marker.sellers->c), 1,filePtr);
   fread(&marker.sellers->d , sizeof (marker.sellers->d), 1,filePtr);

   marker.sellers->cars = malloc(sizeof (*marker.sellers->cars));
   fread(marker.sellers->cars, sizeof (*marker.sellers->cars), 1, filePtr);
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it kind of worked but I can't access the data stored in cars's members. I can't access cars.a or cars.b